# MathJax 3: Change css styles

Tags: mathjax

MathJax 3 loads some inline CSS like

```
mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"] {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Let's say I want no margins, then I can add to my stylesheet:

```
mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Is there a better solution for the above example? Can I modify the styles in the config (`window.MathJax = {}`), so that the loaded inline styles are the correct ones and don't have to be overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready() {
      var CHTMLmath = MathJax._.output.chtml.Wrappers.math.CHTMLmath;
      delete CHTMLmath.styles['mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]'].margin;
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

Above
$$\text{Math Display}$$
Below
```

to remove the margin setting.  Or you can set the margin explicitly with

```js
      CHTMLmath.styles['mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]'].margin = '0';
```

I think that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Update for MathJax 4.0.0 beta

The attribute `CHTMLmath` has been renamed `ChtmlMath`.

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready() {
      var CHTMLmath = MathJax._.output.chtml.Wrappers.math.ChtmlMath;

      // Set a new value
      CHTMLmath.styles['mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]'].margin = '0';

      // Set a new value for a CSS property containing a dash
      CHTMLmath.styles['mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]']["white-space"] = 'normal';

      // Remove a property
      delete CHTMLmath.styles['mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]'].margin;

      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

Above
$$\text{Math Display}$$
Below
```

A CSS property containing a dash in its name will fail, as the dash will be considered as the minus operator, not as part of the property name.

Response adapted from Davide's https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478760/13733324